# Rails image upload API without save data in database and return name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I want to create one API for image upload using CarrierWave with S3. Normal file upload is working but I want to create one API for upload image and return image URL, not need to the same name in the database table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the following gem in your gemfile,
    gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3'

And use below code in the controller (Using APIS)

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'
class Api::V1::UploaderController < ApplicationController
    def create
        file = uploader_params[:image_url]
        file_name =   "#{file.original_filename}"
        upload_file = file.tempfile
        s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'], secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] )

        obj = s3.bucket(ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME']).object(file_name)
        obj.upload_file(upload_file, { acl: 'public-read' })
        success(data: obj.public_url, status: 200)
    end
end
```